# Exception in Python scheduler

Tags: python, exception, scheduler

I'm using Google Colab, and pretty new at Python, but I am trying to build a bot that has three states "green", "yellow" and "red". This is the basic bot, runs every 10 seconds, and if it is running and I press the stop button once, it goes into yellow, but the 2nd time I press the stop button I get "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:". Here is the code:

```py
import sched, time, datetime, json

try:
    def run_bot(sc):
        if botstate == "green":
            print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " doing " + botstate + " state stuff")
            s.enter(10, 1, run_bot, (sc,))
            s.run()
        elif botstate == "yellow":
            print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " doing " + botstate + " state stuff")
            s.enter(10, 1, run_bot, (sc,))
            s.run()
        else:
            print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " FINISHED")


    # START POINT
    print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    botstate = "green"
    s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    s.enter(10, 1, run_bot, (s,))
    s.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    if botstate == "green":
        botstate = "yellow"
        print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " botstate set to " + botstate + ", shutdown state entered")
        s.run()
    else:
        print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " HARD FINISHED")
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You haven't shown us any details at all about the exception.  Are we supposed to guess?

Comment: KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-75c423d3683f> in <module>()
     20   s.enter(10, 1, run_bot, (s,))
---> 21   s.run()
     22 except KeyboardInterrupt:

Comment: @WagsMax: [Edit] that into the question, you can't usefully format an exception traceback in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time you call `s.run()`, you're in a `try` block. When you press ctrl-c, you enter the KeyboardInterrupt exception block.

Then inside that block you call `s.run()` again, but this time you're not in a `try` block, so pressing ctrl-c again raises an uncaught exception.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accepted answer, I changed the exception section and this example now works perfectly:

```
import sched, time, datetime, json

try:
  def run_bot(sc): 
      if botstate == "green":
        print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " doing " + botstate + " state stuff")
      elif botstate == "yellow":
        print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " doing " + botstate + " state stuff")

      # recurse
      s.enter(10, 1, run_bot, (sc,))
      s.run()

  # START POINT
  print (datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " STARTED")
  botstate = "green"
  s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
  s.enter(10, 1, run_bot, (s,))
  s.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  try:
    if botstate == "green":
      botstate = "yellow"
      print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " botstate set to " + botstate + ", shutdown state entered")
      s.run()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " FINISHED")
```